# Need to enable C++11 in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I need to enable C++11 in Codeblocks 16.

Several tutorials explain that all one needs to do is select the "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard `-std=c++11` option in "Settings > Compiler... > Compiler Settings > Compiler Flags", however such an option does not appear in my Compiler Flags:

[image]

Others suggest just pasting `-std=c++11` into "Other compiler options". However this doesn't allow me to build my code and shows this in the "Build Messages" bar:

[image]

I am using Codeblocks 16, with the GNU GCC Compiler that comes with it on Windows 7.

Comment: What version of g++ do you have?  The -std=c++0x flag is for c++11 before it was standardized.

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek: Use CMake, `set( CMAKE_CXX_STARNDARD 11 )`, and generate your CodeBlocks project files via `-G "CodeBlock - Ninja"` or `-G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles"`. ;-)

Comment: By default Codeblocks uses an old version of MinGW GCC. You should update your toolchain with the latest version.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that is not true, CodeBlocks ships with a recent MinGW, and therefore `-std=c++11` is supported since multiple versions in it.

Comment: @CMate Wow, they actually switched to TDM-GCC. Too bad it is 4.9.2, and used exception handling method is atrocious. It is better to replace it anyway.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: what I was saying is that @πάντα ῥεῖ 's remark is false and CodeBlocks does support `-std=c++11` flag since quite a time, so it's no answer for the question.

Comment: try to install tdm-gcc latest version.

Comment: Please show us the **Toolchain executables** tab in the **Global compiler settings**

Comment: @Werdne: How is `-std=c++11` supported when question clearly shows it isn't?

Comment: @el.pescado: issue must be with OP's installation. Already CodeBlocks 12 shipped with a recent enough GCC to support the `-std=c++11` flag. My guess would be that OP downloaded the CodeBlocks installer without GCC and is using a very old version which was installed separately and was found by CodeBlocks on the PATH.

Comment: @Werdne It still seems weird that the option wouldn't be provided in the "Compiler Flags" menu, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could always just select the -std=c++0x option, but another solution is to install more recent mingw version since the problem is obviously the compiler, not Code::Blocks

Answer (score 3):

This is how Code::Blocks 16.1 with the newest included version of GCC (TDM-GCC 4.9.2) is supposed to look like.

[image]

You can check your GCC version with the command

```
gcc --version
```

gcc.exe is located under ./CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin

When downloading from CodeBlock's website, make sure you download [codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/16.01/Windows/codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your compiler, you can download the latest MinGW [here](http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/download).

Once downloaded, that should allow you to select the C++11 standard from compiler flags.

Answer (score -1):

goto settings-> compiler  ->In GNU GCC mode,-> Compiler settings-> Compiler flags -> tick the "Having the g++ follow c++ 11 ISO C++ language standard.."

thats it
[Check this helpful Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNLZEhWZ1og)

Comment: If a GCC version doesn't support `-std=c++0x`, there is no way `-std=c++11` will work.