# How to count the number of times a letter shows up in a randomized string of alphabetical letters

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the number of times each letter of the alphabet shows up in a randomized string that the user creates. I have all the code, minus the portion that would count each time a character is found. I have tried to use a couple of `for...else` loops to figure this out, but maybe I am just not learned to do it correctly, I keep either getting errors or a blank space under the rest of the output.

What I want is for the output to look like this:

`A B C D E F G... 
 1 2 5 7 0 9 2...`

Here is my code and my output so far: [image]
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int i=0, n;
char alphabet[26];
char c;
char RandomStringArray [100];
srand(time(0));

cout <<"How many letters do you want in your random string (no less than 0, no more than 100): ";
cin >> n;

for (int i=0; i<=25; i++)
        alphabet[i] = 'a' + i;

while(i<n) {
    int temp = rand() % 26;
    RandomStringArray[i] = alphabet[temp];
    i++;
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<RandomStringArray[i];
cout<<"\n\n";

/*for(c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c)
   cout<<" "<<c;
   cout<<"\n";
   */

map<char,size_t> char_counts;
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) ++char_counts[RandomStringArray[i]];{

for (char ch :: alphabet) std::cout << ch << ' ';{
     std::cout << '\n';
}
for (char ch :: alphabet) std::cout << char_counts[ch] <<'';{
        std::cout << '\n';
     }
      }
}
```

Comment: You have an `Array` containing all the letters of the alphabet. Why not create another `Array` that will hold the counters for the letters? Then just math with the chars to make `a` 0, `b` 1 and so on. Then just do something like `counters[theChar - 'a']++;`

Comment: `std::unordered_map<char, int>` is good for this, especially if your character ranges are non-contiguous (e.g. distinct upper and lower case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` is good for this sort of thing. It's similar to the array approach of holding counts for each character but is more convenient to use, especially when the character ranges you're interested in are non-contiguous.

When you index a `std::unordered_map` the mapped value will be returned by reference, so you just increment it. If it doesn't exist it's created and default initialized (zero initialized for integer types).

So all you need to do is:

```
std::unordered_map<char, std::size_t> char_counts;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) ++char_counts[RandomStringArray[i]];
```

After this, `char_counts` holds the total occurrence counts for all characters in the string. e.g. `char_counts['a']` is the number of occurrences of `'a'`.

Then to print them all out you could do:

```
for (char ch : alphabet) std::cout << ch << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';

for (char ch : alphabet) std::cout << char_counts[ch] << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: When i try that approach, it tells me that the std:unordered_map is not a member of std. I still used `#include <unordered_map>` ,yet it doesn't want to work.

Comment: @Zethos It's two colons, not one. It's `std::unordered_map`. But since you already have `using namespace std;` you can omit the `std::` anyway.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, even with doing what you suggested, my code blocks program is very limited, it wont allow me to use that code because its saying its not in its library.

Comment: @Zethos Oh, what version of C++ are you compiling with? You need at least C++11 for this to work. Here's a link for [enabling C++11 in Codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723856/need-to-enable-c11-in-codeblocks)

Comment: Thanks for that, I can't seem to use the @ function to mention your name in comments, I think I had that figured out. This is just a novice follow up question. In order to print out those occurrences , what would i put in my `cout` line?

Comment: @Zethos I've edited the question with a cout code block for printing all the counts. The @ thing is sometime wonky for me as well - seems to fail randomly.

Comment: Thanks I saw it, and yeah that @ thing is annoying, at times. Thanks for the input, I updated the main code for this question because of it.Now I am getting use to do with expected expressions and such, those screenshots are updated too. I don't what to take up your time, but I wonder if you could show me what else I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Zethos Oh, the `::` in the for loops should be just one `:`. It's the syntax of a range-based for loop.