# Fix 'no matching function for call to ...' error?

Tags: c++, opengl, codeblocks, glut, glui

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/richardroyal/SR-Simulade-Special-Relativity-Simulator/blob/master/aberration.cpp) .cpp file in Codeblocks (only change is adding #include for windows.h to beginning).

It uses OpenGL, GLUT, and GLUI. I think I've gotten OpenGL and GLUT to work in Codeblocks but GLUI is still giving me some issues. At first, I downloaded GLUI from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glui/) and copied glui.h into `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\GL`.

I was getting an error around line 455:

```
void control_cb( int control ){

    if (control == 5){
    GLUI_Master.close_all();
    (...)
};
```

which stated there was an undefined reference to GLUI_Master.

I then realized that the GitHub repository also had [a GLUI header file](https://github.com/richardroyal/SR-Simulade-Special-Relativity-Simulator/blob/master/glui.h) so I deleted the other header file and copied this new one into the same place as above.

I was able to get a little further now, getting an error around line 508:

```
void createSettingsMenu(){
    (...)
    new GLUI_Button( settings, "Update", 5,control_cb);
    //settings->set_main_gfx_window(mainWindow);
    (...)
};
```

which stated there was no matching function for call to:

```
GLUI_Button::GLUI_Button(GLUI*&, const char [7], int, void(&) (int)).
```

I'm not sure what this means, but it also says

```
**note: candidate: GLUI_Button::GLUI_Button()
  note: candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided**
```

around line 847:

```
GLUI_Button( void ) {
    sprintf( name, "Button: %p", this );
    type         = GLUI_CONTROL_BUTTON;
    h            = GLUI_BUTTON_SIZE;
    w            = 100;
    alignment    = GLUI_ALIGN_CENTER;
    can_activate = true;
};
```

I'm assuming this is related to the error but I'm not sure how to fix this -- I thought this error was surely caused by an issue in setting up GLUI with Codeblocks.

Comment: `GLUI_Button( void )` as implemented takes 0 arguments however the code passes it 4. I don't think the code worked when posted to github.

Comment: Here is a `GLUI_Button()` that takes 4 arguments. https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2006/fall/cs381/ref/glui/classGLUI__Button.html

Comment: Here is a better link for `glui` https://github.com/libglui/glui/blob/master/include/GL/glui.h

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you so much - How would you recommend fixing this? How would I write the function differently to take the 4 arguments in GLUI_Button(GLUI*&, const char [7], int, void(&) (int)) instead of 0?

Comment: I am saying the GLUI header that is included in the SR-Simulade-Special-Relativity-Simulator github is wrong. It does not match the expectation of having 4 parameters. You probably need to use the official source which I gave you the link. You may also have to do some work porting this. Considering that the repository had posted non-working code there may be other bugs.

Comment: @drescherjm Oh okay thank you - Sorry for the misunderstanding. I replaced that header file and am now getting this... 
    #error This file requires compiler and library support for the 
    ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be 
    enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: Do what the instructions say.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723856/need-to-enable-c11-in-codeblocks